# Blacklight: Retribution XP required per Level?

Tags: blacklight-retribution

I have been playing some Blacklight: Retribution recently and can't seem to find (either on the wiki or in-game) **how much XP is required to advance to the next level**. Is it the same amount for each level? Does it scale? Is there a certain playstyle that'll net me more XP per match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect to XP required per level I have data [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1folzBEWStBGA9PFTdeFuPx-dCfz04g-GL948vzyd53E/edit?usp=sharing). Worth noting, you'll see some anomalies such as the one between level 7 and 8. I'm guessing this is due to patching.

To subjectively answer your second question I've found that KC and SIEGE give way more XP than the other game modes (especially SIEGE) due to your base XP being based on your CP for the match.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how accurate that chart is, but [here](http://blacklight.wikia.com/wiki/Levels) is one.

Comment: Haha, that's the result of my survey :). It's accurate as of the date it was posted.